# GPG Decrypt command not returning any output file

Tags: command-line, encryption, openpgp, gpg4win

I generated gpg public and Private Key using **gnupg (2.4.0)** on windows cmd(let's call it: Source Machine) and encrypted a .csv file.

Now I am on DataBrick workspace and created cluster with following configuration:
*Runtime Environment: 12.2 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12)

Node Type: Standard_f4 Machine*

***DataBrick GPG version: 2.3.1**

1. Dropped the Generated Public and Private Key files (.pgp) in DataBrick Filestore(DataBrick Local Folder)
2. Created a Notebook to write shell commands
3. Executed following shell command to import the Keys (success)

   %sh
   gpg --import /dbfs/FileStore/GPG/PUBkey.gpg
   gpg --batch --no-tty --yes --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase "1234" --import /dbfs/FileStore/GPG/PVTkey.gpg
4. And following commands to decrypt the file: ( NO Response)

   %sh
   gpg --no-tty --yes --always-trust --pinentry-mode=loopback --yes --passphrase "1234" --output /dbfs/FileStore/GPG/File1.csv --decrypt /dbfs/FileStore/GPG/File1_csv.gpg

**BUT IT DOES NOT RETURN ANY OUTPUT DECRYPTED FILE NOR ANY ERROR OR WARNING MESSAGE.**

NOW THE STRANGE THING IS THAT IF I DECRYPTE THE SAME ENCRYPTED FILE IN SOURCE SYSTEM WHERE KEYS GENRATED AND FILE ENCRYPTED, IT WORKS FINE AND GENRATES THE DECRYPTED FILE.

ALSO IF I USE THE SAME PUBLIC KEY TO ENCRYPT THE .CSV FILE WITHIN DATABRICK ENVIRONMENT USING FOLLWING COMAND THEN GENRATED ENCRYPTED FILE DECRYPTES SMOOTHLY WITH SAME POINT 4 COMMANDS.

For the sake I tested with both .asc and .gpg extension for both data file and keys but no luck.

Moreover I tried using GNUPG python library in DataBrick and wrote following code but it shows same behavior:  Executes fine but no decrypted file as output.

```
import gnupg
import codecs

try:
  gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/dbfs/FileStore/homed') 
except TypeError:
  gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir='/dbfs/FileStore/homed')

with open('/dbfs/FileStore/GPG/File1_csv.gpg', 'rb') as f:    
  status = gpg.decrypt_file(f,  passphrase='1234',output='/dbfs/FileStore/GPG/File1.csv')
```